# Can you turn a folder of PHP files into a netbeans project?

Tags: php, netbeans

I have a folder with several subdirectories containing PHP files. At the moment I open each file individually in Netbeans. However, I would like to open this folder as a project, so I can use features like searching for a line throughout the entire project. Is this possible in Netbeans? What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new project, set sources directory to the one you have with current files 
(might want to back up the files before if anything goes wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Go in Netbeans. Select  **Files->New Project**. A window will open, in that select **PHP** in Categories. Click Next. In **Project Name** give the name of your project(as seen in netbeans), in **Sources Folder**  select the path to your project and click Next. In Run Configuration Make the settings according to your requirement to run the project. Now in **PHP Frameworks** Select ypur desired framework or just leave it blank and click **FINISH**.
You will See your project in Netbeans now.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `file->New Project` and select `PHP` in category and follow the instruction.
In Source folder you need to choose your files folder so that it get listed.

Answer (score 1):

go to **FILE**->**new Project**->select **php** in **categories in left pane** and **php application with existing sources** as  **Projects** **in the right pane** ->next -> next till finish

Answer (score 1):

When you add any directory in netbeans as a project, it add its only directory under the project directory. So if you need to add the numbers of directory in netbeans being a project,  then i would like to suggest firstly to collect all directory in parent directory. then add it as a project.
Here is an explaination:-
directory- dir
lets you have dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4.
and according to you  mentioned above all dir are projects.
You have to create a dirA and all dir1, dir2, dir3,and dir4 are subdirectory of dirA.
so the folder under dirA nbprojects(created by netbeans) will take care of all directories being the subdirectory of dirA.